# IEnumerable array is always null...WebAPI

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a comma separated string and passing it to my WebAPI method like so:

```
var projectids="";
                    for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
                        projectids += chk[i].VMIProjectId + ",";
                    }
                   //projectids = "1,2,3"
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "http://localhost:52555/device/6/AddProjectsToDevice",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(projectids),
                        success: function (msg) {
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    });
```

I 'm reaching the WebApi method successfully, but my IEnumerable array projectIds is always null. Here's the method:

```
 [HttpPost]
   [Route("device/{deviceId}/AddProjectsToDevice")]
   public IEnumerable<VMI_DeviceLinkedProject> AddProjectsToDevice([FromUri]long deviceId,[FromBody] IEnumerable<long> projectIds){}
```

How do i pass my comma separated list of ids to my WebAPI method? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now your controller action is getting a comma separated string of numbers and not a JSON array (`"[1,2,3,4]"`), which is why the model binder isn't working:

```
var projectids = [];
for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
    projectids.push(chk[i].VMIProjectId);
}
```

And then the stringified array should bind to the `IEnumerable<long>` properly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing it as a csv value you can pass it as an array using the same code as below,

```
var projectIdList =[];

for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
   projectIdList.push(chk[i].VMIProjectId);
}
```

Similarly change the parameter name in api method also as projectIdList and pass it.